# Why does AccountManager.invalidateAuthToken requires AccountType instead of AccountName?

Tags: android, accountmanager

When invalidating authorized tokens from `AccountManager` using `invalidateAuthToken`,

Q1: Why does the function requires the `Type` of the account when using the `Name` of the account seems to make more sense?

Q2: By giving it the `Type`, does `invalidateAuthToken` wipe out **all** auth tokens under that account type?

Answer (score 2):

Q1: type is not as restrictive as name, it implicitly indicates that you are dealing with a group and not an individual, IMHO.

accountType defines what type of account you are fetching in the accountManager.  for example: "www.google" for google accounts.  given a bundle inside a callback, you find out the accountType by using:

```
private class GetAuthTokenCallback implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        try {
           bundle = result.getResult();
           String auth_token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
           String auth_account_type = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
```

Q2: according to the [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#invalidateAuthToken%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), the syntax is:

```
public void invalidateAuthToken (String accountType, String authToken)
```

accountType must NOT be null, but authToken may be null.  if you omit authToken, you clear all tokens for that accountType